# Docker Compose...Builds with wrong node version ( among other problems )

Tags: node.js, macos, docker

Inherited project..everything broke last week..

This is on MacOS 10.11.
3 projects using node 6.9.5...DockerFiles said: FROM node:6.9 I changed that to node:10.20. I pulled that from the hub.docker, and it shows up in my docker images list.

However, when I use docker-compose up - it always says it's using 6.9.5.

Since I have bunches of other problems, I'm going back to basics, and just verifying I am using what I THINK I am using.

In addition, I told nvm to use v10.20 for default node version on my machine..

I can successfully "docker build ." on the three programs that the compose runs..

The crux of the matter is that one of the programs won't build, and I believe it started because it was using an ancient version of a library that updated itself into oblivion. I get weird errors in totally unrelated libraries when trying to run ( in this case, express-handlebars ).

Any tidbits on this would be appreciated. I understand that this missive is a bit vague, but I've been whacking this for over a week and getting nowhere. The projects are large and complex, and I wonder if I've damaged my Docker or what.

Thanks.

Jolly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker-compose up` doesn't rebuild, and `docker build .` doesn't assign the tag that `docker-compose` looks for. Do `docker-compose up --build` instead.

Comment: Not sure how is it possible but this way worked for me. In other cases it was failing with incorect node version. But thanks for sharing this!!